# Why is this while loop not executing when code is compiled with Numba?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nan, numba

I have a small piece of code like so:

```
@njit
def looptest():
    value0 = np.NaN
    while math.isnan(value0):
        print('Nan 2: ', math.isnan(value0))
        break
```

Surprisingly, that print never executes.

Numba says math.isnan is supported: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/developer/autogen_math_listing.html#math.isnan

So I tried with `cmath`, which is also supposedly supported. Same result: the loop never executes, but only when compiled with Numba. If I disable JIT compilation it prints just fine.

I then added some debug info:

```
@njit
def looptest():
    value0 = np.NaN
    print('Nan 1: ', cmath.isnan(value0))
    print(value0)
    while cmath.isnan(value0):
        print('Nan 2: ', cmath.isnan(value0))
        break
```

I see, even when compiling with Numba, that `isnan` seems to resolve to True correctly:

```
Nan 1:  True
nan
```

However, to my suprise again, the second print inside the while loop does not execute when compiled with Numba.

I tried reducing optimizations using `NUMBA_OPT=1` and `NUMBA_OPT=0` - same result.

What is going on? How can I write this code so that the while loop will execute the same whether compiled with Numba or not?

Comment: This runs fine on my machine. Have you tried to call `looptest.py_func()` to see the expected output?

Comment: It turns out I cleared the Numba cache and things worked again... not sure what happened there, I'll just call it a mystery. Or a bug.